# Edit GitHub documents directly from Visual Studio Code

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I use Windows 10 Home and I have a GitHub account with just one repository with about five code-oriented files (`.md` files these are).

I put these files in GitHub because of my habit to put there code-oriented files and because I want to share them in general and that an easy search engine access would be available for them.

As a non Git language user I always use the GitHub GUI and desire VSCode instead. I want to edit each such file directly from Visual Studio Code, just as I would edit any local file in some folder, or any remote file in Google Backup and Sync folder:

After the file is accessed by VSCODE, every save is a commit and the message is default (no pull requests are processed); this is basically the result.

I found no information on how to do so but it is maybe possible by some tweak.
**What is the way to achieve that?**

<sub>To clarify: I treat my storage in GitHub as storage of code-oriented files per se, without any necessity to associate it with *Git*, while in Google Backup and Sync I generally put non code-oriented files.</sub>

Comment: You want to edit files that are in a git repo on a GitHub remote on your local machine but *not* use git? Why are they in a git repo, then? Also note that git doesn't necessarily mean PRs, but version controlling is very much the point.

Comment: You can try by configuring SSH and using `code` command to open the file, but you would need to get into `git` protocolling. There is no real reason to do it BTW, but there is a way (And it would use git-based knowledge).

Comment: @jonrsharpe I tried to address your comment-questions in an edit; I invite you to go through the edit.

Comment: @AlexanderSantos I don't know why you determine there is no need to do so --- I find VSCODE possibly comfortable for that and I don't recognize a reasons to reject this notion.

Comment: There is no real need because VSCode would use Git to do that. Without Git, you would be reinventing the wheel, you can just use Git inside VSCode's Source Control and edit it as you want.

Comment: @AlexanderSantos I still don't recognize why there is no real need - as a general rule; say there is a bypass, what is the problem?...

Comment: @ShadowyShade this would give you a pain to implement and would do as same as a Git client simply does. Basically, as it doesn't give you any relevant help, as you would still need to use your "created client", there is no real need. You can try it for educational purposes, but i really don't see why, as you would still be using "Git-based" techs.

Comment: How would you expect the result to look? A commit for every change (keystroke, save, ...)? What messages? You could use e.g. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kenhowardpdx.vscode-gist for gists, but if you're using an actual repo just use the *already integrated* git functionality.

Comment: Whatever happens by GitHub, which is very much what you described (default message is fine with me) is fine with me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. GitHub is a Git server, thus you need to use a Git client to manipulate its contents.

Comment: I thank you for the concise answer. I have learned from you and I greatly appreciate it.